# How do software packages compute the gamma probability density for large $\alpha$?

Tags: gamma-function, computational-mathematics, gamma-distribution

Consider the gamma density parameterized in terms of shape $(\alpha)$ and rate $(\beta)$:
$$
f(x)=\frac{\beta^\alpha}{\Gamma(\alpha)}x^{\alpha-1}e^{-\beta x}\mathbf 1_{x>0}.
$$
Direct computation of the density function from the above expression becomes difficult for large $\alpha$ so how do modern software packages compute it in this situation?

We do have ways of computing $\log\Gamma(\alpha)$ for large $\alpha$ so its seems reasonable to evaluate
$$
\log f(x)=\alpha\log\beta-\log\Gamma(\alpha)+(\alpha-1)\log x-\beta x
$$
and then exponentiate the result. But I'm skeptical this is how it's done.  Can someone please elaborate?

Comment: Is [this](https://arxiv.org/abs/2109.08392) the sort of thing you're looking for?

Comment: @MishaLavrov That is certainly related but I'm specifically interested in how the entire pdf is evaluated.